# Tinymce show blocks position

Tags: html, css, tinymce

I am using [tinymce](https://www.tinymce.com) editor.

Can we change the default [show](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/visualblocks/) blocks (tag names like h1, h2 etc.) to top-left side of each visual block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer.

In the file,

```
tinymce/js/tinymce/plugins/visualblocks/css/visualblocks.css
```

give this css properties to each and every class.

```
background-position-y: top;    
background-position-x: initial;
```